# jscolor picker, how to use onchange event for a button?

Tags: javascript, html, onchange, jscolor

I am using [jscolor](http://jscolor.com/) v2.0.4 from East Desire. All works fine but the `onchange` event does not work if I use a button.

In the `onchange` event sample on the webpage is an input field used. but I use a button element and here is only the `onFineChange` event possible. Why?

Here is my code:

```
<button style="border:2px solid black; width:80px; height:30px" class="jscolor {valueElement:'chosen-value', closable:true,closeText:'Close me!', onFineChange:'updateColor(this)'}">Pick color</button>
R, G, B = <span id="rgb"></span>

<script>
function updateColor(picker) {
    document.getElementById('rgb').innerHTML = Math.round(picker.rgb[0]) + ', ' + Math.round(picker.rgb[1]) + ', ' + Math.round(picker.rgb[2]);
}
</script>
```

If I change the `onFineChange` to `onchange` then it does not work. What can I do?

Comment: Why not use the `onclick` event? Buttons don't support the `onchange` event, if you think about it, they technically have a `value` to change. You can see the supported elements for `onchange` [on the W3Schools onChange Docs](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp)

Comment: onchange and onFineChange are in the jscolor implementet.
the onFineChange event fires more often if i drag on the color field. the onchange Event only fires after the mouse button is released in the color picker. i need this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pay attention to the example markup. onchange was part of the input element, not part of jscolor implementation.

```
<input class="jscolor" onchange="update(this.jscolor)" value="cc66ff">

<input class="jscolor {onFineChange:'update(this)'}" value="cc66ff">
```

If you see the markup then you'll understand that onchange is not jscolor's implementation.

If you check the source code of jscolor you'll also find that. onChange is meant to fire only on inpyt type elements, not on buttons

```
dispatchChange : function (thisObj) {
        if (thisObj.valueElement) {
            if (jsc.isElementType(thisObj.valueElement, 'input')) {
                jsc.fireEvent(thisObj.valueElement, 'change');
            }
        }
    },
```

ref: https://github.com/EastDesire/jscolor/blob/master/jscolor.js#L671

So if you want onchange event, then you have to change your button to input type

or you can create input type="button" and then listen to the event onchange, because the plugin only cares about input not the type

```
<input class="jscolor" id="btnPicker" type="button">
<script>

document.getElementById('btnPicker').addEventListener('change', function(e){
    updateColor(this.jscolor)
})
function updateColor(picker) {
    document.getElementById('rgb').innerHTML = Math.round(picker.rgb[0]) + ', ' + Math.round(picker.rgb[1]) + ', ' + Math.round(picker.rgb[2]);
}
</script>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer and the explanation.
Is there any chance to fire a event after the mouse button on the color picker is released?

Comment: you can create a input type button and listen to fake event onchange. let me update the answer with that code

Comment: Many thanks for your help. **All works fine** :) It helps me to finish my IOT-Project to control LED-Stripes over wifi.

Comment: That's great news!!!. Happy coding and experimenting man. All the best!